# Initialstate not updated after success login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux

I just learned how react-redux works.

I created a backend with express js and used axios in the fronted(authentication). After I login, it just gives me a success status.but I can't understand why after success login the state still like initialState in reducer
login.js

```js
 
import React,{ useState} from 'react'
import { connect, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {login} from '../../actions/authentication'
import './auth.css' 
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Login = ({history, login}) => {

     const dispatch = useDispatch();
     const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
       email: "",
       password:""
     });

     const hundleChange = (e) => {
       setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

     }

     const hundleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       dispatch(login(formData));
       history.push("/");
     }
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="forms">
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <LoginForm   email = {formData.email}
            password = {formData.password}
            hundleSubmit = {hundleSubmit}
            hundleChange = {hundleChange}/>
        </div>
        <p>Do you not have account</p>
         <Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
  
     auth : state.auth
}
)
export default connect (mapStateToProps, {login})(Login);
```

authentication.js

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { AUTH_FAILURE, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS } from './types'

//login user
export const login = (formData) => async (dispatch) =>{
    //formData ={email, password}
    try {
     const res =  await axios.post("/api/auth/login", formData)
     dispatch({
         type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
         payload: res.data
     });
     console.log("here data", dispatch.payload)

    } catch (error) {
        console.dir(error);
        const response = error.response.data;
        if(Array.isArray(response)){
            response.forEach((err) =>
            {
                alert(err.msg);
            });
        }
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_FAILURE
        });
    }
}
```

authReducer.js

```js
import {LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS} from '../actions'

const initialState = {
    token: null,
    user:null,
    isLoading: false,
    isAuth: false
};

export default (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
    switch(type) {
         case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
         return {...state,
                 user: payload.user,
                 token: payload.token,
                 isLoading: false,
                 isAuth: true
                         
        };

        default:
            return state;
    }

};
```

[redux_devtools1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFBgP.png)
[redux_devtools2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCKaI.png)

Comment: Try just using `login(formData)` instead of `dispatch(login(formData))`.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan thank you ,i try it but the problem persist

Comment: What do you see in the console when you remove the `dispatch` call?

Comment: Try `login(formData)(dispatch)`.

Comment: login(formData) ;console.log("formData here",formData) not render anything even the action not show data and login(formData)(dispatch) is equivalent to dispatch(login(formData))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,the problem was with the import
import {LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS} from '../actions/types'

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import {LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS} from '../actions/types'

//login user
export const login = (formData) => async (dispatch) =>{
    //formData ={email, password}
    try {
     const res =  await axios.post("/api/auth/login", formData)
     dispatch({
         type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
         payload: res.data
     });
     console.log("here data", dispatch.payload)

    } catch (error) {
        console.dir(error);
        const response = error.response.data;
        if(Array.isArray(response)){
            response.forEach((err) =>
            {
                alert(err.msg);
            });
        }
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_FAILURE
        });
    }
}
```